# How to Implement Max Heaps and Item Class To Create Greedy Algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, greedy

```
public class MaxHeap {

    class Item{
private double weight;
private int value;
private int ID;
private double factor;

public Item(double weight, int value, int id, double factor){
this.weight = weight;
this.value = value;
this.ID = id;
this.factor = factor;
}

public double getWeight() {
return weight;
}

public void setWeight(double weight) {
this.weight = weight;
}

public int getValue() {
return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
this.value = value;
}

public int getID() {
return ID;
}

public void setID(int ID) {
this.ID = ID;
}

public double getFactor() {
return factor;
}

public void setFactor(double factor) {
this.factor = factor;
}
}
 

  private int[] Heap;
    private int size;
    private int maxsize;
 
    // Constructor to initialize an
    // empty max heap with given maximum
    // capacity
    public MaxHeap(int maxsize)
    {
        // This keyword refers to current instance itself
        this.maxsize = maxsize;
        this.size = 0;
        Heap = new int[this.maxsize];
    }
 
    // Method 1
    // Returning position of parent
    private int parent(int pos) { return (pos - 1) / 2; }
 
    // Method 2
    // Returning left children
    private int leftChild(int pos) { return (2 * pos) + 1; }
 
    // Method 3
    // Returning right children
    private int rightChild(int pos){ return (2 * pos) + 2; }
 
    // Method 4
    // Returning true of given node is leaf
    private boolean isLeaf(int pos)
    {
        if (pos > (size / 2) && pos <= size) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
 
    // Method 5
    // Swapping nodes
    private void swap(int fpos, int spos)
    {
        int tmp;
        tmp = Heap[fpos];
        Heap[fpos] = Heap[spos];
        Heap[spos] = tmp;
    }
 
    // Method 6
    // Recursive function to max heapify given subtree
    private void maxHeapify(int pos)
    {
        if (isLeaf(pos))
            return;
 
        if (Heap[pos] < Heap[leftChild(pos)]
            || Heap[pos] < Heap[rightChild(pos)]) {
 
            if (Heap[leftChild(pos)]
                > Heap[rightChild(pos)]) {
                swap(pos, leftChild(pos));
                maxHeapify(leftChild(pos));
            }
            else {
                swap(pos, rightChild(pos));
                maxHeapify(rightChild(pos));
            }
        }
    }
 
    // Method 7
    // Inserts a new element to max heap
    public void insert(double weight, int value, int id)
    {
        Heap[size] = value;
 
        // Traverse up and fix violated property
        int current = size;
        while (Heap[current] > Heap[parent(current)]) {
            swap(current, parent(current));
            current = parent(current);
        }
        size++;
    }
 
    // Method 8
    // To display heap
   
 

    public int extractMax()
    {
        int popped = Heap[0];
        Heap[0] = Heap[size--];
        maxHeapify(0);
        return popped;
    }
    
 

    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {

 
        MaxHeap maxHeap = new MaxHeap(67);
 
        // Inserting nodes
        // Custom inputs
        maxHeap.insert(23,505,0);
        maxHeap.insert(26,352,1);
        maxHeap.insert(20,458,2);
        maxHeap.insert(18,220,3);
        maxHeap.insert(32,354,4);
        maxHeap.insert(27,414,5);
        maxHeap.insert(29,498,6);
        maxHeap.insert(26,545,7);
        maxHeap.insert(30,473,8);
        maxHeap.insert(27,543,9);
       
        maxHeap.print();
 
        
        System.out.println("The max val is "
                           + maxHeap.extractMax());
    }
}




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    }
    
}
```

I was tasked with trying to create a max heap and and item class and implement the two in solving a basic knapsack problem. I have been playing around with it and I cannot figure out how I can use my max heap class and item class in order to create a greedy algorithm. Any help is appreciated. I am also not sure how necessary the "knapsack" class is as I had just taken that from geeksforgeeks and was trying to take bits and pieces and implement it into mine. Apologies if this is too much code.

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: I am trying to implement a greedy method within the heap class that has uses items with  capacity, ID, value, and weight parameters in order to solve a knapsack problem.

Comment: That's not a question, that's something you're trying to do.  A question might be something like "what is wrong with this max heap class?" or "why is this code not compiling?"